# Provisional patents formal font size and style

Tags: patent-applications, provisional-application

I wonder if anyone can direct me to an article on which font to use for headers and text in a patent. I have searched some articles without luck. I want my provisional patent to be as formal as the other provisional patents.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The U.S. Patent Office sets out the font and line spacing for non-provisional patent applications in MPEP 608 (37 CFR 1.52) as:

> > (2) The specification (including the abstract and claims) for other than reissue applications and reexamination or supplemental
> >     examination proceedings, and any amendments for applications
> >     (including reissue applications) and reexamination proceedings to the
> >     specification, except as provided for in §§ 1.821 through 1.825, must
> >     have:
>
> (i) Lines that are 1 1/2 or double spaced;
>
> (ii) Text written in a nonscript type font (e.g., Arial, Times Roman,
>   or Courier, preferably a font size of 12) lettering style having
>   capital letters which should be at least 0.3175 cm. (0.125 inch) high,
>   but may be no smaller than 0.21 cm. (0.08 inch) high (e.g., a font
>   size of 6); and
>
> (iii) Only a single column of text.

https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s608.html#d0e42440

Please note that there are no definitive standards for a provisional application as it is never examined.  However it should be legible in order for it to be checked if necessary for support for the non-provisional application.

Comment: My browser crashed and I lost all accounts details. So, I had to create a new account in here. Thanks a lot for the detailed reply. Much appreciated. If hope a moderator selects this as the right answer on my behalf.